# animate width of rectangle from center in raphael.js

Tags: javascript, html, raphael

I have a question about the `.animate()` Api in [Raphael.js](http://raphaeljs.com/)
There is a rectangle which I would like animate the `width` and `height`.

```
r.animate({ width: 50, height: 50 }, 1000, "bounce");
```

But I want to expand it from the center of that rectangle, not the left-top. Does anyone of you know how to do it?

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/QZ9Pz/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a better way to do this without calculation. If you know how much bigger you want to make your object, then you should animate the scaling.

Here is the **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/QZ9Pz/1/)**

```
r.click(function() { r.animate({ transform:'s2' }, 500); });
```

Note that `transform:'s2'` means scale it 2x. Hope this helped ;)

**EDIT** if you want to have this animation works conterminously, just write **`transform:'...s2'`** instead.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `x` and `y` to move the retangle and simulate it growing from center.

```
r.click(function() { r.animate({ width: 100, height: 100, x: 75, y:75 }, 500); });
```

[**`Here is a FIDDLE`**](http://jsfiddle.net/Urfs6/)

Comment: good thought, works flawless. but I don't intend to calculate the position and half of the width. But if there isn't any other solution, I should go for it.